# unable to group by on multiple column in Pivot sql Query

Tags: sql-server

I am working in a restaurant project. I have 4 table for sale module.

1. order master.
2. order details.
3. itemEntry
4. waiter_info

**They require a report which will show each item sale quantity for each waiter.**

```
 MENU_NAME  MENU_ID PRICE   Total   Foisal  Kamal   Sajib
    Naan       2    10.00   8          6    2        0
    Parata     1    10.00   10         6    4        0
    Vaji       3    30.00   15         8    6        1
```

My query is below:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
     + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Waiter_Info) AS Waiter
print @ColumnName
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'

 SELECT  * from vw_ItemWiseSale
 pivot
 (
    sum(QUANTITY) for WAITER in ('+ @ColumnName +')) as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

My output is:

```
 MENU_NAME  MENU_ID PRICE   Total   Foisal  Kamal   Sajib
 Naan          2    10.00     20    NULL    2       NULL
 Naan          2    10.00     60    6      NULL     NULL
 Parata        1    10.00     40    NULL    4       NULL
 Parata        1    10.00     60    6       NULL    NULL
 Vaji          3    30.00     30    NULL    NULL    1
 Vaji          3    30.00     180   NULL    6       NULL
 Vaji          3    30.00     240   8       NULL    NULL
```

Please help me to get expected output item wise which mentioned in 3 line.(i,e each row for every item)

Comment: change 'for waiter in' to 'for name in'

Comment: Please display some sample data and the code for the view you're using.

Comment: brother John Bell - sorry for unable to comprehend you my problem.above my query i have added required output as well as below of query i added query output.

Comment: brother ANK why i will use name instead of waiter. i want to pivot on waiter name column as well as item name.please compare 2 output i mentioned above.